# Wake On LAN works after linux shutdown but not windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ethernet, wake-on-lan, dualboot

My PC has dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, installed on separate hard drive.

Some background: when the PC power on, it goes to the grub menu, and default on Ubuntu. each time I want to use the Windows, I switch the grub menu (I wrote a bash script, so I usually WOL the PC, SSH in Ubuntu, and run the script and wait for windows start, then I can use windows with Remote desktop)

The problem is WOL only works if I shutdown the PC from Ubuntu. And if I shutdown PC in the Windows, the WOL can never wake up the computer. So each time I finished work with the windows, I restart and let it boot back to the default Ubuntu, then I shutdown the Ubuntu, this way, I can WOL the PC next time.

FYI, The WOL used to work with the Windows before I installed the Ubuntu.
The ethernet port is Intel I-219V, on the Windows, I have disabled Hibernate, fast boot, and disabled Ethernet power saving or whatever it called.

Any help on this? What should I look at with the Windows to solve this issue? Or is it supposed to be function like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In windows select "Power options"---What the Power buttons do---Shutdown Settings---Remove the tick from Turn on Fast Startup(recommended).Now when you shutdown there will be reserve power in NIC.

Comment: Can you share what setting you made in UBUNTU as our WOl dosent work on ubuntu if its shutdown on suspend it works.